# Overlay css not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I have html page with a div element. It is actually css to hide page when modalpopup is opened. It is working fine in firefox but not in IE 6. Can anyone please suggest.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>   
    <style type="text/css">
        .overlay1
        {
            position: fixed !important;     
            background-color: #000;       
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0px;            
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;            
            filter: alpha(opacity=20);
            opacity: 0.2;
            -moz-opacity: 0.2;
            -khtml-opacity: 0.2;
            -webkit-opacity: 0.2;
            z-index: 10004;            
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay1">
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: People still support IE6? O_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: IE6 does not support `position:fixed;`
Possible solution:

```
* html .fixedBlock{
    position: absolute;
    top: expression(eval(document.body.scrollTop) + "px");
}
```

Another problem - as I know, opacity for IE 6 should be set like this:

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
```

Comment: And also without height property, div is not getting rendered for < IE 6.

Comment: @Sundeep Just interesting - are you seriously talking about IE4,5? I can believe that IE6 is in a list of supported browsers, but older browsers...? What task do you have?

Comment: haha..no I just saw the script of some commercial websites, they are setting the height for < IE6. And most of my application users use Windows XP, so IE6 support is expected.